# Access env variables when running Vite React app using Dockerfile

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, vite, fly

I have a Vite React app which uses env variables to talk to an API:

```
const API_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL;
```

I am deploying this app to Fly.io with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18 as build

WORKDIR /web

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /web/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# This needs be referenced in fly.toml's internal_port
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I have the `VITE_API_URL` set in my Fly.io container's env and have checked that it exists.

However, when I deploy the app, the `API_URL` ends up as `undefined`. I think it has something to do with nginx not having access to it.

I had deployed this other Dockerfile when developing:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /web

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

And this one had access to Fly.io's secrets/env variables. I suspect its because I'm running the Vite code directly using `npm run dev`. But now that I'm running it through nginx, I think I might need to do something different to access the same env variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vite needs [environment variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode) at **build time**.

You've got two options...

1. Add a `.env.production` file into your Docker build. Eg

   ```properties
   # .env.production
   VITE_API_URL=https://your.production.api/
   ```
2. Pass a build argument to your `fly deploy` command and use it to set an environment variable

   ```sh
   fly deploy --build-arg API_URL="https://your.production.api/"
   ```

   ```docker
   # Dockerfile
   FROM node:18 as build
   WORKDIR /web
   COPY package*.json ./
   RUN npm install
   COPY . .

   ARG API_URL
   ENV VITE_API_URL=${API_URL}
   RUN npm run build
   ```

   I think you can also [set build args](https://fly.io/docs/reference/configuration/#specify-docker-build-arguments) in your `fly.toml` file under `[build.args]` if you prefer

Comment: Adding a `.env.production` worked for me, thanks! Which method do you think is the best practice? I guess the .env.production file exposes the API url in the app source, but that might not be a big issue?

Comment: Kind of depends. If you want it more flexible and variable, keep it in Fly. One thing to consider is that you [can't use secrets in build args](https://community.fly.io/t/secret-docker-build-arguments/5481) but you are building a front-end app so nothing is secret anyway :D

Comment: Should the `.env.production` file be checked into git?

Comment: Can't see why not but Vite convention is to use `.env.production.local` for something not in VCS